# Post upgrade deployment, service is stuck in Transitioning

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am following the manual walking of upgrade domain mode of Azure deployment. When i issue walk upgrade domain REST api and check the status of operation ID, i get success. I get this for all upgrade domains within no time.
Even once the upgrade is done and i have walked the last domain, my service still remains in transitioning state. Is there a way i stay in domain until my domain comes out of transitioning and only then move to the next domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk the last domain + 1. Once you do that the deployment will go into the Running state.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you choose manual Update Domain walk over automatic walk?

Automatic update domain walk will ensure that the deployment will only move to the next domain if the current domain satisfy all quorum check requirement. For manual walk, you need to ensure your service is up manually.